# ASP.NET Unobstrusive perform both client and serverside validations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation

Are the asp.net MVC unobstrusive validation data annotations have client-side validation only or it do perform server-side too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data annotations also perform client side validation. For example, say you have the following data annotation on the `FirstName` property of a model used for a form:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

If javascript is enabled, the validation will occur client side and the form will not submit unless the user enters something in the textbox. If javascript is disabled, or if your missing the appropriate scripts to perform client side validation, the validation will occur on the server side. However, you have to check if `ModelState` is valid and return the view if it is not valid:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Do something here if you need to, then return the view
    return View();
}
```